# Tomcat in Eclipse resets configuration files after adding

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, configuration

I am using Tomcat 6.x and Eclipse J2EE Kepler. For reasons mentioned in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919502/updating-a-jar-library-does-not-reflect-in-tomcat), I sometimes need to delete the Tomcat from the Servers list and re-add it.
[image]

The weird thing is: after I re-add the server, two configuration files `server.xml` and `context.xml` revert to a previous state! let's call it **S**. I cannot really tell what **S** is - it definitely is a state I once had, but it lacks some newer changes. For this reason my webapp does not work and I have to revert these two files in the `workspace/Servers` folder.

I'd love to fix this by updating **S**. However, I am unable to find the source of **S**, where Eclipse takes it from - I tried fulltext-searching my computer for files that look like the `server.xml` and `context.xml`, but to no avail. Specifically, I updated these two files in the `conf/` folder of my Tomcat installation, but it did not help.

Where could Eclipse be keeping **S**? In some weird DB in the workspace metadata? Could it be using the local history?...

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Eclipse then there should be a folder called Servers in your workspace. When you start your server for the first time, it copies over the tomcat conf files into this eclipse project. So no matter if you change your actual context.xml from outside, eclipse will override it with what is stored in the 'Servers' folder.

If you still need the eclipse to take control of your tomcat installation directory, you need to primarily update this file from within the eclipse.